# Angularjs - How to redirect in another state using resolver

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Start by saying I am totally new to AngularJS and I don't have a great experience with it.

What I try to do, is to redirect users to another state, using `resolve` in the route state. My route state code is like that:

```
const defaultTemplate = require('path-to-homepage-template/homepage.tpl');

module.exports = {
    states: [
        {
            state: 'homepage',
            config: {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: defaultTemplate,
                title: 'homepage',
                controller: 'HomepageController',
                controllerAs: 'homepage',
                resolve: {
                    HomePageFormSeoResolver: 'HomePageFormSeoResolver'
                }
            }
        }
    ]
};
```

Then my resolver class looks like that:

```
const AngularInjected = require('app_core/angular-injected');

class HomePageFormSeoResolver extends AngularInjected {
    static get $inject() {
        return [
            'Logger',
            'CONFIG',
            '$location',
            '$state',
            '$q'
        ];
    }

    constructor(...dependencies) {
        super(...dependencies);

        this._resolve();
    }

    /**
     * Responsible to check if the the get param `formSeo` exists and it's value
     * is `yes`
     * @private
     */
    _resolve() {
        const deferred   = this.deps.$q.defer();
        const get_params = this.deps.$location.search();

        // noinspection JSUnresolvedVariable
        if (
            typeof undefined !== typeof get_params.formSeo &&
            'yes' === get_params.formSeo
        ) {
            console.log('Here we are !!!!');
            this.deps.$state.go('signup-confirmation');

            deferred.resolve();
        }
        else {
            deferred.resolve();
        }

        return deferred.promise;
    }
}

module.exports = {
    init: ngModule => {
        ngModule.service(
            'HomePageFormSeoResolver',
            HomePageFormSeoResolver
        );
    }
};
```

So, when I run this script, I see in the browser console the message `Here we are !!!!` but the redirection doesn't work.

I have also try in the same code blog the following statements:

```
deferred.reject();
```

or

```
return;
```

or

```
return false;
```

So, I don't know if there's any other solution for my case or if I am doing anything in wrong.

Do you see anything wrong?

*(Keep in mind that the static method `$inject()`, assigns all the dependencies in the class `deps` property. )*

Answer (score 0):

You can return a promise from your resolver function that will indicate whether to continue navigating to the state or not. If you decide to navigate somewhere else - reject the promise and specify the proper state:

```
resolver($q, $state, $timeout, auth) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    // $timeout is an example; it also can be an xhr request or any other async function
    $timeout(function() {
      if (!auth.isLoggedIn()) {
        // user is not logged, do not proceed
        // instead, go to a different page
        $state.go('noLoggedInPath');
        deferred.reject();
      } else {
        // everything is fine, proceed
        deferred.resolve();
      }
    });

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

i'm not sure abut it but may be it helpful to you.

Comment: As I already have described, I have try the `reject` solution, but yet doesn't work.